# Question about specifics of boolean-algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, math-history

Why does it use only 1 and 0 in boolean algebra? But can you explain it without attracting logic gates.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

See [Two-element Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) (but it does not use only $0$ and $1$ symbols; there are variables: $x,y,\ldots$ and $=$ and $\land, \lor$, etc.)

The reason for the choice of $1$ and $0$ to represent $\text {True}$ and $\text {False}$ are historical.

See George Boole's [The Mathematical Analysis of Logic (1847)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/boole/#MathAnalLogi1847).

In the "class" interpretation of the calculus, Boole denotes with $1$ the "universe" from which variables $x$ and $y$ take their meaning.

The "minus" sign is the complement operation: $1-x$, and thus we have $0$, the complement of the "universe", i.e. the null class.

In the "propositional" interpretation of the calculus, the "hypothetical universe", $1$, shall comprehend all conceivable cases.

And see [page 51](https://books.google.it/books?id=zv4YAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA51):

> The symbol $1 - x$ selects those cases in which the proposition
> $x$ is false. But if the proposition is true, there are no
> such cases in its hypothetical universe, therefore $1-x = 0$, or

> $$x=1.$$

> The elective symbol $x$ selects all those cases in which the
> proposition is true, and therefore if the proposition is false,

> $$x = 0.$$